# IE9 Double drop down issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Customize image was added to the select box, every browser it was displaying fine except in IE9. I can see two arrows one is customized arrow image and another drop down Icon. How can i remove that Drop down Icon that come on IE9. Please help me if any one knows.

```
.dropdown {

   height: 90px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background: url(../images\valdropdown.png) no-repeat right;
   background-size: 10% 100%;
   position:relative;
   display:inline-block;
}



.dropdown select {
background: transparent;
-o-appearance:none;
-prefix-appearance: none;
-ms-box-sizing:content-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  appearance:none

padding:5px;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 1;
border: none;
border-radius: 0;
height: 50px;
z-index: -1;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
text-indent: 0.01px;
text-overflow: '';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done something like this. [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/yhwbrr8v/)

In example, a fixed width set on `select` and wrap a div with a lower width and `overflow:hidden` in order to mask/hide the dropdown. It has full support and essentially does hide the arrow in all browsers.

HTML

```
<div>
    <select>
        <option>one</option>
        <option>two</option>
        <option>three</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    width: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
select {
    width: 100px;
    border: 0px;
}
```

OR with pure `CSS`

```
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```

OR with `jQuery` selectbox replacement.
It's a jQuery plugin.
[jQuery selectbox plugin](https://code.google.com/p/select-box/)

Comment: Hi,  But if we use width size is greater than the div or container width then they drop down menu is not lined up with the div or select box. From the above solution i can fix removing arrow but drop down is not lined up. Can you please let me know if you have any idea removing unwanted arrow from IE9 and making the drop down lined up with the select box. Thank you very much.

Comment: will help you in better way if you share HTML code too